# NSJSONSerialization creates garbage

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, ios9, nsjsonserialization

I have some problems with creating a `NSString`-representation (JSON-string) of a `NSDictionary` using `NSJSONSerialization`. I have used JSONKit before, but since its kind of deprecated in iOS9 (and crashes), I switched to `NSJSONSerialization`.

This is my code:

```
// `userSettings` will be of type NSMutableDictionary*

NSData* data= [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userSettings options:0 error:&error];
NSString* settingsString= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes];

currentUser.settings= settingsString;   // NSString* property
```

Now, from time to time, this code works, but then sometimes the `settingsString` will be `nil`. And when I inspect the data object in the debugger, the `bytes` property shows the JSON-String followed by some random garbage, like this:

```
1 = 0x00007ff1ba814000 "{\"residua
...
lculatePlanned\":\"0\",\"wizardUserId\":\"\"}UITextColor\x91UISystemColorName\x94UIBaselineAdjustment\x8cUISystemFont\x89NS.intval\x8eUIShadowOffset\x94UIAutoresizeSubviews\x8dUIContentMode\x85NSRGB\x8aUIFontName\x8bUITextLabel\x8eNSInlinedValue\x91UIDetailTextLabel\x99UIUserInteractionDisabled\x9dUITableCellBackgroundColorSet\x94UINibEncoderEmptyKey\x87NSWhite\x8cNSColorSpace\x8fUITextAlignment\xa3UINibAccessibilityConfigurationsKey\x92UIAutoresizingMask\x99UIProxiedObjectIdentifier\x87UIAlpha\x87UIWhite\x9aUIFontDescriptorAttributes\x8cUIFontTraits\x86NSSize\x95UIColorComponentCount\x91UIMinimumFontSize\x86UIText\x96UIMultipleTouchEnabled\x8dUIDestination\x94UIMi..."
                                             ^ start of garbage after end of dictionary
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `+ stringWithUTF8String:`, it relies on a A NULL-terminated C array of bytes and there is only a NULL terminator by chance and it may be well after the end of the charactery you expect.

Instead use:

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Ex:

```
NSString *settingsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Better to never convert the data to an NSString at all. NSData will work just fine. And JSON isn't guaranteed to be UTF-8 anyway.

Comment: There may be a valid reason: I do this occasionally during debugging.